# XDocument find node value where other node value equals my search

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I do not know how to iterate through an XML document to find a node value that belongs to an item that has a specific value in another node. Let me explain more clearly...

Here is my XML:

```
<Items>
   <Item>
      <Id>id 1</Id>
      <Item>item 1</Item>
      <LastModified>2016-01-01</LastModified>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Id>id 2</Id>
      <Item>item 2</Item>
      <LastModified>2016-02-02</LastModified>
   </Item>
</Item>
```

I would like to find the value of `<LastModified>` where `<Id>` = id 2 so that I would get the following date: 2016-02-02. 
A solution in C# using XDocument would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `Item` element that contains the `Id` with your value, and then get its `LastModified` element:

```
var lastModified = (DateTime) doc.Descendants("Item")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Element("Id") == "id 2")
    .Elements("LastModified")
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZFbgTA) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very simple solution, works perfectly!